# Stata csdid - Callaway and Sant'anna DD estimator

Tags: interpretation, stata, difference-in-difference

I'm implementing Callaway and Sant'anna's difference-in-difference (DD) estimator for my study using the csdid code in Stata.

I get the following output in Stata; however, I'm unsure of how to interpret the results correctly. For example what is the difference between Tm7 and Tp7?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Tm estimates are pre-period treatment estimates and the Tp estimates are post-period treatment estimates. For example, Tm7 is the impact of the treatment on your outcome 7 periods before the treatment was implemented.

You can verify this by running the `csdid` command. It will give you the exact same results, however the  Tm prefix is replaced with a "-" (for pre period) and the Tp is replaced with a "+" (for post period).